# Getting Promise pending as value in the variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver

I working with selenium web-driver and this is my first time working with node.js promise.

I am trying the get value from getText and getAttribute and store them in an array, but getText and getAttribute keeps returning Promise

Here is my code:

```
var a;
var nameText;
var linkText;

(async function example() {
  let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('firefox').build();
  try {
    await driver.get('https://example.com');
    await driver.findElement(By.name('email')).sendKeys('example@example.com');
    await driver.findElement(By.name('pass')).sendKeys('pasword');
    await driver.findElement(By.id('u_0_b')).click();

   await driver.getPageSource().then( function() {

   driver.get('https://www.example.com/posts').then(function() {
    driver.findElements(By.className('title')).then(function(elements) {
      elements.forEach(function (element) {
        a = element.findElement(By.tagName('a'));

        nameText = a.getText("value").then((value) => { return value; });// Here is the issue

        linkText = a.getAttribute("href").then((value) => { return value; });// Here is the issue

        data.push({name: nameText, link: linkText});
        console.log(data);

      });
    });

    // a.then((text, href) => {
    //   console.log(text);
    //   console.log(href);
    // });
  });
});
  } finally {
    // await driver.quit();
  }
})();
```

Comment: you may want to do await on it and assign value in `.then` method direct

Comment: All those places where you do things like `driver.get().then` and `driver.findElements().then` should be replaced with `await driver.get()` and `await driver.findElements()` ideally. Async/await features are there to make everything easier for you

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, by making it async and await I am getting all the names first and then the links, I want synchronous behavior here that get the loop element Text and link at the same time, is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they're returning promises, then your easiest option is to make it an async function and await the results:

```
elements.forEach(async function (element) {
    a = element.findElement(By.tagName('a'));

    nameText = await a.getText("value").then((value) => { return value; });// Here is the issue

    linkText = await a.getAttribute("href").then((value) => { return value; });// Here is the issue

    data.push({name: nameText, link: linkText});
    console.log(data);

  });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the promise is resolved by it but now I am getting all the names first and then the links, I want synchronous behavior here that get the loop element Text and link at the same time.